# Azure Function - stopped invocation without any reason

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I setup an Azure function which is set to run with a timer trigger every 10 minutes (CRON schedule is set to 0 */10 * * * *) . The function is running and everything works well, but suddenly after 3 days, the function is no longer invoked. When I restarted the service, it returns to normal and runs every 10 minutes. This problem happened 3 times.

Is there any explanation for it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on consumption plan or a dedicated web app?

I'm assuming this is dedicated web app, as consumption has a built in timeout of 5 min to avoid runaway functions.

You can set a timeout value for functions in [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json) which will kill these runaway functions and restart automatically. You can also add verbose logging settings in host.json to help determine why these functions aren't completing.

Comment: It might be a logging issue in portal. Based on server logs, the function ran consistently the entire time, both in the -dev and -pro apps (Always On is correctly enabled on both).